# Implementing CMU pocketsphinx android demo in android NDK with SWIG and JNI

Tags: cmusphinx

I am facing problem in implementing cmu pocketsphinx recognition android demo in android NDK.

The error is

The import edu.  cmu.  pocketsphinx.   Config cannot be resolved
The import edu.   cmu.   pocketsphinx.   Decoder cannot be resolved
The import edu.    cmu.   pocketsphinx.   Hypothesis cannot be resolved
The import edu.     cmu.   pocketsphinx.    pocketsphinx cannot be resolved

I am not sure this is the problem with SWIG or JNI

when i referred some website i came to know that SWIG as to generate above classes . Please let us how to handle SWIG and JNI on this issue

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and I had to install SWIG then remake the pocketsphinx binary.

On Linux, this was:

```
sudo apt-get install swig
cd /pocketsphinx/
./configure
make
make install
```

After that I copied in the .java files from the /pocketsphinx/swig/edu/cmu/pocketsphinx/ to your Android project's jni/edu.cmu.pocketsphinx folder as seen in step 6 here (http://swathiep.blogspot.com/2011/02/offline-speech-recognition-with.html).

I still get compile errors on my ndk-build (I'm still working through it) but it sounds like this is what you needed.

Comment: what is the instead of ./configure  in windows ? because it gives me '.' is not recognized

Comment: This link has some Windows pocketsphinx instructions.  Hope it helps: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx